# android tv -Reference of search image in browse fragment

Tags: android-tv, leanback

I have a scenario where I need to set focus dynamically on search icon in browse fragment .For that I need to get reference of the search icon.Any idea how it can be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[BrowseFragment class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/support/v17/leanback/app/BrowseFragment.java#BrowseFragment.0mOnFocusSearchListener) accesses search icon using title view's `getSearchAffordanceView()`

```
 private final BrowseFrameLayout.OnFocusSearchListener mOnFocusSearchListener =
         new BrowseFrameLayout.OnFocusSearchListener() {

     @Override
     public View onFocusSearch(View focused, int direction) {
         // If headers fragment is disabled, just return null.

         if (!mCanShowHeaders) return null;
            final View searchOrbView = mTitleView.getSearchAffordanceView();

    .
    .
    .
```

Since `mTitleView` is `BrowseFragment`'s private member, you cannot get search icon reference directly. The only properties you can control for search affordance in the fragment title are: visibility and color. Visibility is controlled by the presence of a search listener.